# How do I unfreeze an Account?

Tags: freeze-token-account, associated-token-program

I minted a bunch of NFTs and frooze the token accounts. Now I cant transfer and close them. What is the function to unfreeze them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I found it.
It's ThawAccount instruction.

Here are the docs, I found it under FreezeAccount section:
https://spl.solana.com/token